# How to listen for a Lookup change

Tags: angular, ng-lightning

I cannot find anywhere in the documentation how to detect a change of the Lookup component. The same goes also for other components that do not use ngModel, like the Pick. There is even related [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ng-lightning/ng-lightning/issues/323) with no response for over 2 months.

Here is example code:

```html
<ngl-lookup [(value)]="value" [lookup]="lookupAsync" field="formatted_address" [(pick)]="address">
  <template nglLookupLabel>Type an address:</template>
  <div nglLookupHeader class="slds-text-body--small">Most relevant cities</div>
  <template nglLookupItem let-ctx>
    <div class="slds-media__body">
      <div class="slds-lookup__result-text">{{ctx.formatted_address}}</div>
      <span class="slds-lookup__result-meta slds-text-body--small">Place ID: {{ctx.place_id}}</span>
    </div>
  </template>
</ngl-lookup>
```

And related plucker can be found on the components page in "Lookups" section:

- http://ng-lightning.github.io/ng-lightning/#/components

Am I missing something? I am really confused to see so many components not using ngModel.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You did not save your plnkr before posting

Comment: @Skeptor Thank you, I was referring to original plucker placed on their website. I didn't notice it was not a normal link. I have provided a link to the components page instead.

Comment: Let me understand your requirement. Whenever we enter in lookup you want to do something ? you want to be able to handle the event in component ?

Comment: @Skeptor Whenever user chooses the location I want to be informed about it and handle an event in a component. You could imagine filtering functionality... something changed, I want to refresh results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[(pick)]="address"
```

1. Above syntax is a two-way data binding. In the sense it binds data from component to input and input to component .
2. It is a shortcut to `[pick]="superhero" (pickChange)="setSuperhero($event)"`

where `setSuperhero` sets updated value to `this.superhero`.

**Solution to your problem:**

change `[(pick)]="superhero"` to this :

```
[pick]="superhero" (pickChange)="superheroPicked($event)"
```

Inside component :

```
superheroPicked(superhero){
    this.superhero = superhero; 
    console.log(superhero);
}
```

The above will set superhero to new value when selected and also prints the value in console.

Related **Plnkr** : https://plnkr.co/edit/FaTlh3wzreKkaKZORjKx?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's exactly what I needed, I see that it also works with "Pick" component, hope it's also true for the rest. Now I need to ask, did I miss something in the documentation? And also do you know why it is done this way? I imagine it makes it harder to use with forms etc. I would have to create my own component based on this implementing ControlValueAccessor. Or am I missing something again?

Comment: Its a general convention in angular. I checked the source code of the library to make sure they are also following the same convention. If it answered your problem, can you mark this is as answer. It wont waste others time .

Comment: Its not that complex with forms also. I am sure they integrated with their forms component too. I never worked on this framework so not sure. Get back if you find a trouble then